# Minecraft 1.9 /tp Entity UUID provided is in invalid format

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using a Repeat Unconditional Always active command block on Minecraft 1.9. When I use this command:

```
/tp @p[x=~-2,y=~,z=~,r=0] ~ ~ ~1
```

I get the error message `The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`. Why is this?

Comment: Just a tip: use `@a` instead of `@p`. `@p` means the nearest player, but `@a` means *any* player that follows those conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format

This error typically occurs when no target was found. In your case, you have a malformed selector which the game will instead read as literal input, which is not in valid UUID format (e.g. `e39b92b5-f831-4f28-b785-219e65eb4cfd` is a valid format).

The `~` character cannot be used in selectors, breaking syntax.

However, the `r` parameter has undergone some major changes in 1.9. Instead of looking for a target in a whole blockspace, it looks for players in an actual radius of 0 from the coordinate origin. It is unlikely that general usage of `r=0` will locate a player. You will want to increase the radius to 1 or use the delta parameters, which do still target based on blockspace (such as adding just `dx=0` in place of `r=0`).